# Hidden Markov Model Initial Guess

Tags: mathematical-optimization, hidden-markov-models

I'm training a 2-state HMM on a large English text (first 50,000 characters of Brown Corpus, including only letters and spaces), my algorithm follows from Mark Stamp's tutorial (www.cs.sjsu.edu/~stamp/RUA/HMM.pdf).

Since the observations include only the 26 letters and space, initially I gave each observation (within a state) a probability of 1/27, then modifying each by 0.0001 while keeping the row stochastic.

Running the trainer for 50 iterations gives me very minute incremental improvement in log[P(O|lambda)], where lambda is the updated model. Further, in the observation matrix of the final model, the probability for each observation is almost identical across the two states (see http://pastebin.com/xVVYNhGs).

I figured I'm stuck on a local maximum, so I altered the initial guess for observation matrix to match Stamp's, and it actually gave me a updated observation matrix differing by states* within the same number of iterations.
(50 iterations: http://pastebin.com/U0AgrJ2N; 100 iterations: http://pastebin.com/yAkruNjs)

My question is, my altered initial observation matrix (Emission prob) clearly broke me out of the sad local maximum; but how would I go about finding/optimizing this initial guess?

Comment: I don't know if we should migrate this question or not, but I think http://cs.stackexchange.com might be better suited for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to this is given in the HMM tutorial [paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Bayes/rabiner.pdf) by Rabiner, Section V-C, Pg 273:

> Basically, there is no simple or straightforward answer to the above
> question. Instead, experience has shown that either random (subject to
> the stochastic and the nonzero value constraints) or uniform initial
> estimates of the prior probabilities and the transition matrix is
> adequate for giving useful reestimates of these parameters in almost all
> cases.
>
> However, for the emission matrix, experience has shown that
> good initial estimates are helpful in the discrete symbol case, and
> are essential (when dealing with multiple mixtures) in the continuous
> distribution case.**
>
> **Such initial estimates can be obtained in a number of ways**, including:
>
> **1)** manual segmentation of the observation sequences into
> states with averaging observations within states,
>
> **2)** maximum likelihood segmentation of observations with averaging,
>
> **3)** segmental k-means segmentation with clustering,
>
> etc.